# Accessing APIs in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I am developing solution where there are three webapi projcets.
Each of them is secured with JWT tokens mechanism.
So far webapis had not need to communicate. Finally they will be deployed on azure separetly and they will be using the same database.

I could generate a token with infinite lifespan and store it somewhere in the database, but something tells to me this is not right way to solve this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Question: How to allow them to communicate other way than generating a token with infinite lifespan?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: "So far webapis had not need to communicate. Finally they will be deployed on azure separetly and they will be using the same database." so they're still not communicating with each other? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Now they need to communicate between them.

Comment: And how will they be communicating between each other?

Comment: Using http requests, but if there are better aprroches I can make a change.

Comment: So they will be no different to each other than clients of your APIs?

Comment: Yep. That's right. If user change a value in database through app1, app2 should be notified in order to refresh they view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190507/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-tylkonachwile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for [SQL Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency). An SQL dependency allows you to subscribe to an event that gets triggered when the result of a command differs. Something like so:

```
// I'll assume that a connection is already open
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SQL Command goes here")
{
    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += (object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) => 
    {
        // Handle OnChange here
        Console.WriteLine(e.Info);
    }

    // You can do all the things with the SQL Command here as you normally could
    // for example execute it if it's a SELECT and read data
}
```

Be careful when using SQL dependencies as they're a bit more time consuming/ expensive as one would think, so try to keep them to a minimum